# Convert a basic sql query to django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms, django-orm

I want to display the course name along with the question count in a table. Need help to convert below query to a django ORM:

```
SELECT DISTINCT exam_course.course_name,
                COUNT(exam_question.question)
FROM exam_course
INNER JOIN exam_question ON exam_question.course_id = exam_course.id
GROUP BY exam_question.course_id
```

[image: Views.Py]

[image: Models.py]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: have you tried using annotations with count ?

Comment: Refer this Article for more details [Article Link](https://hakibenita.com/django-group-by-sql#how-to-group-by-distinct)

Answer (score 0):

Use annotate with count as commented...use in this manner, replace accordingly your requirements:

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.annotate(total_amount=Sum('order__order_items__amount'),number_of_invoices=Count('pk', distinct=True))
```

Comment: Can you see above screenshot am not able to render course name in html